# json.load() fails when loading multiple json files from sub-directories

Tags: python, json

I am trying to load all the json files in a folder and its sub folders. And getting these errors

> json_data = json.load(json_file)
> File "/usr/lib/python3.9/json/**init**.py", line 293, in load
> return loads(fp.read(),
> File "/usr/lib/python3.9/json/**init**.py", line 346, in loads
> return _default_decoder.decode(s)
> File "/usr/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
> obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
> File "/usr/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
> raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
> json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

This code works and reads all the json files in a directory. But if there are any sub directories then it fails

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(self.opt_dir_path):
    for file in files:
        json_file = open(os.path.join(root, file), 'r')
        json_data = json.load(json_file)
        print(json_data)
        json_file.close()
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to load something that isn't a JSON document. Print out the filenames as you go through your loop. Which one causes the error? What does it look like?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but this would be a great place to make use of Python's [`with` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement).

Answer (score 0):

Because, like the name suggests, walk goes into the subdirectories. If all your files are in the top level directory, then just use `os.path.listdir` instead and make sure the file ends with ".json".  If you did intend to "walk" then you better make sure every file in every subdirectory is json valid, or do some kind of validation prior to loading.

Here is the code for the first option

```
for file in os.path.listdir(self.opt_dir_path):
    if not file.endswith('.json'):
        continue
    with open(os.path.join(self.opt_dir_path, file), 'r') as jfile:
        json_data = json.load(jfile)
```